# Visual Studio post-build copy failing (but works on the command line)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, post-build-event

In VS 2010, I have a post-build event copying project assemblies into a common .dll folder.  The .dll folder is mapped by a virtual drive (R:).

On running, I get the following: `The command "copy /y "C:\CommonDLLs\Utilities.dll" "R:\"" exited with code 1.`

The thing is, when I run `copy /y "C:\CommonDLLs\Utilities.dll" "R:\"` at the command prompt, it works correctly.  I'm running VS as an admin, so I should have permissions to execute the command.  Other people using the same code from source control are having no problems, but I'm stumped as to what to fix to get the copy to work correctly.  Anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT: more information
The R drive is mapped/created/populated initially by a .bat script that I run as an admin as well.  if I update my scripts to run to the location the R drive points to, everything runs ok, so I think this might be a drive mapping issue.  The thing is, I(as a local admin) have full control over both the folder and the drive mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that the virtual drive does not exist under the Admin account and as such cannot be found.

Either don't run VS as Admin, or set up the virtual drive in an command prompt running as Admin.